# How to create a NOT IN where clause Doctrine_Query?

Tags: mysql, symfony1, doctrine

I am developing in symfony 1.4 using Doctrine ORM. I can't create a NOT IN where clause using an array with ids. This is my code:

```
$results = Doctrine_Query::create()
  ->from('Asset a')
  ->where('a.id NOT IN (?)', implode(',', $ids))
  ->execute();
```

The sql for this query that is generated is this one:

```
WHERE (a.id NOT IN ('1,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,17,18,20,24,25,26,29,30,28'))
```

As you can see is treating the array filled with ids like an string. I tried also without the implode of the array but I get this error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens
```

The array $ids containing the excluded ids is a plain numeric one.

I can't find out what is the correct syntax for this clause. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `whereNotIn` ([old doc but still ok](http://www.symfony-project.org/doctrine/1_2/en/06-Working-With-Data)).

```
$results = Doctrine_Query::create()
  ->from('Asset a')
  ->whereNotIn('a.id', $ids)
  ->execute();
```